# mysql_connect() causing 500 error

Tags: php, mysql

I am a bit new to web development. So there might be a trivial thing that I might have missed and am not able to figure out by searching online for some time. Here is the problem

In my PHP script I am connecting to the data as shown below

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This function works fine when I run it from shell prompt on the server using "php -f" command
But when I try to execute this script using a browser session, it gives an error.

"HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request"

The server php version is 5.3.3 and it is on Cent OS.

Comment: [Don't use mysql_* extension](http://www.php.net/en/mysql_query) as they’re deprecated. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: Check your Apache/PHP error logs.

Comment: Check the web server error log, it may give more details about the error

Comment: You need to look in your error log to see the exact error. This could be that mysql extension not available in the php apache module. Your error message is a generic 500 error the server throws when the script is having a problem.

Comment: Check your server logs, or turn on `error_reporting` so that PHP will show you the error message in the browser. A 500 error means that something went wrong, but it really doesn't tell us much more than that; you need to dig a bit deeper than that to find the actual error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that selinux was activated on centOS. I had to set the 
allow_user_mysql_connect bool using the command

```
setsebool -P allow_user_mysql_connect on
```